# FormAuthentication Redirect to Different login page C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, authentication, webforms

I am creating an ASP.NET webform application where I have a different level of users. I have read about `FormsAuthentication` and if I am implementing it, I have to provide a `loginUrl` in web.config file. Everyone is redirected to the same loginUrl after successfull authentication.

But For my site, I have users with different credentials. So when a user with **Admin** credential is login, system redirect it to `Mysite.com/Admin/Index.aspx` page. IF a user is login with **Student** credential, he is redirect it to `Mysite.com/Student/index.aspx` page.

Can anyone please guide me or suggest me how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: loginUrl is the url to the login form page, not the page the user gets redirected after successfuly logging in. All you have to do is, after successful authentication, redirect to the appropriate page based on the user's permissions.

Comment: @elolos: Could you please elaborate more with some example? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per @elolos comment, all you have to do is Redirect them to the correct page after you have logged them in.

For example

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model){
   if (!(ModelState.IsValid) || !(Membership.ValidateUser(model.username, model.password))){
     // handle error
   }

   .. set session variables, cookies ,etc ..

   if (User.IsInRole("Admin")){
      return Redirect(Url.Action("Index","Admin"))
   }
   if (User.IsInRole("Student")){
      return Redirect(Url.Action("Index","Student"))
   }

   ... and so on ...
}
```

Comment: sorry If I forget to mention it's a ASP.NET webform application not MVC web application.

Comment: Ah, never done webforms.. sorry ...  I do know that the forms auth model is common between both systems, so the code you will write should be similar.

Comment: Like @CtrlDot says, the code you have to add in the code behind file should be fairly similar (e.g. Response.Redirect() instead of Redirect()) and just has to perform authorization and check the user's role. You can try writing some code and should you face a problem, you can update your question to include information about it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19740.forms-authentication-with-multiple-login-pages.aspx

But imho if you have different login pages you need to check redirect URL or if you don't have redirect URL you need to check refferer URL to show correct login page. Otherwise for session timeouts your app will be ended by showing wrong login page.